# Page numbering at the bottom and right top in one document

Tags: page-numbering

I've been looking on how could I make page numbering as shown below.
[image]

I have no idea to make it, because everytime I tried to make the numbering, it's always at the same position. Please help me out.

I also have checked this post [Roman numerals at the bottom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156109/roman-numerals-at-the-bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a page style for the differing components. In the example below I (re)define `plain` - used for each first page of a `\chapter` - to be completely empty. Also, `frontmatter` and `mainmatter` is defined to have the page number set in the respective formats (`\roman` and `\arabic`).

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
}
\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%
  \pagestyle{plain}% Just like plain page style
  \fancyfoot[C]{\roman{page}}% Roman page number in footer centre
}
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
  \pagestyle{plain}% Just like plain page style
  \fancyhead[R]{\arabic{page}}% Arabic page number in header right
}

\let\oldfrontmatter\frontmatter
\renewcommand{\frontmatter}{
  \oldfrontmatter
  \pagestyle{frontmatter}
}
\let\oldmainmatter\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{
  \oldmainmatter
  \pagestyle{mainmatter}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\maketitle

\cleardoublepage

\sloppy\lipsum[1-20] % Some front matter content

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter} % Start of main matter content
\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```